# Setting Up MySQL Database on Virtual Host

Tags: phpmyadmin, virtualhost

I set-up a virtual host called "myroot" in MAMP Pro on my local machine. When I open phpmyadmin, it shows that the the server "localhost" is running.

How do I switch it to "myroot"?

I'm developing a new site on the virtual host called "myroot". And I need to make a new database. Should I have the site's new database located in myroot, as well? If so, how do I switch from localhost to myroot?

Does it matter? Should I develop my site on one host and keep the mySQL database on the other?

Thank you.

-Lamxidi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I ended up making the MySQl database in phpMyAdmin on the localhost instead of myroot.

-Laxmidi